# Python parsing csv exported from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, csv, parsing

I would like some help on a problem that i'm having. I need to parse a dataset exported from mysql and this format is in comma delimited .csv with 9 rows of data in the following format:

```
             Date, Data, Data, Data, Numbers, Names, Data, Data, Data
```

Sorry if i'm being vague since i cannot disclose the exact contents of the rows

i need to parse data from row 6 and check if the user has made a valid entry and compares it with the csv file and i need to sum the data in row 5

```
    import csv
    gt_users = raw_input("Enter user you want to search for: ")

    opn_file = open("[REDACTED FILE NAME]", "r")
    read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

for row in read_csv:
    Name = row[5]
    Number = row[4]
    Names.append(Name)
    Numbers.append(Number)
```

and i'm not sure where to proceed from here i've search for answers but none of them work but i'm sure i'm doing something wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to do something like:

```
import csv

data = []

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        data.append((row[5], float(row[4])))

gt_user = raw_input("Enter user you want to search for: ")
total = 0

for name, number in data:
    if gt_user == name:
        print "Found {}, number is {}".format(name, number)
        total += number

print "Total for {} is {}".format(gt_user, total)
```

Rather than creating two separate lists of values for the columns, store them together using a tuple. By doing this you can read them easily as pairs.

Also, by reading the csv file first, you could add a while loop to keep prompting for user input without having to keep rereading the file each time.

There are ways to make this run faster, but for a small text file this linear approach will be adequate.

Use `with` when opening a file in Python. This will ensure that the file is automatically closed after use.

To calculate a total for all matching numbers, just add a `total` variable and increment it for each match, displaying the value at the end. Make sure the number in `row[4]` is first converted to an integer before storing in `data`.

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind me asking. That method works well but how would i go about finding all instances in column[5] and sum all instances pertaining to column[5] in column[4]. Thank you in advanced much appreciated.

Comment: Just add a running `total` which is displayed at the end.

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions since i just got lumped into this project and i'm fairly new to python. How would i go about and do that since the the data set for column[4] are doubles ex: 1.23 0.444555555. Accuracy is need for this project.

Comment: Use `float()` instead of `int()`

Comment: I did       total += number
        float(total)      and i get                                                                   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: I had updated the script, take a look where I added it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help on my issue. Learned quite a bit from my mistakes.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. Finding all variation of a string like im looking for all instances ex: Linux and Linux-2333                                       Find them both to be summed.